# merge two files on basis of common data

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files. First file contains the userid and Name. Second file consists of userid and a number value for which that user id has access on. My requirement is to use the contents of both files and copy the output in third file in this format.

File#1 contents :

```
jaina39 Aayush Jain
pawarm02 Mukesh Pawar
dubeyd01 Devasya Dubey
sharmar01 Ram Sharma
```

File#2 contents:

```
jaina39 01
jaina39 02
jaina39 11
jaina39 12
jaina39 31
jaina39 35
jaina39 39
jaina39 41
jaina39 54
pawarm02 01
pawarm02 02
pawarm02 11
pawarm02 21
pawarm02 33
pawarm02 44
dubeyd01 31
dubeyd01 41
dubeyd01 51
dubeyd01 2047
dubeyd01 2049
sharmar01 100
sharmar01 101
sharmar01 111
sharmar01 2000
sharmar01 2011
```

Desired Output File:

```
Aayush Jain
01,02,11,12,31,35,39,41,54
Mukesh Pawar
01,02,11,21,33,44
Devasya Dubey
31,41,51,2047,2049
Ram Sharma 
100,101,111,2000,20111
```

Comment: Can you describe little bit more with output

Comment: Basically, the output i am looking for should pickup the Name from first file and add it on top of second file on the basis of username.. 
I have ten usernames in the first file and these 10 users have access on multiple objects and thus there are multiple lines for same user in second line. For better readability, we want Names to be merged in the output file on top of access

Comment: Let me write for you .. just check when i answer the answer if required we can modify ok

Comment: Probably possible, but "shell scripting" is very much the wrong tool. Can you use `awk`, `perl`, ...?

Comment: If awk can be used, that'd be great!

Comment: please write more lines of your files

Comment: @AayushJain   May be this link will help you to get the desired output try solution provided by Ed Morton `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5]=$2" "$3" "$6;next} $2 in a{print $0, a[$2]}' file1 file2`. If it works all good otherwise then make little changes in awk command … it is already been answered by several user for this type of question  link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342954/awk-joining-two-files-on-a-specific-column

Comment: @codeholic24 I tried the above solution but somehow it didn't worked the expected way probably I didn't understood the syntax correctly. Any help on this would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ Ids[$1]= Ids[$1]? Ids[$1] "," $2: $2; next; };
            { print $0; print Ids[$1]; }' file2 file1
```

read all Ids into *awk* array from the `file2`, then print the entire line from the `file1` and the matched Ids for that Id.